# How to add different data types to firestore in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In the firebase console you can add a boolean as a field or even an int. I am trying to add such a data type via code and it generates an error. The code I have looks like

```
 Int Score;
 Bool completion;

void addDetails() {
 Map<dynamic, dynamic> data = <dynamic, dynamic>{
  Score: 1.0,
  completion: false,
};
documentReference.setData(data).whenComplete(() {
  print('Uploaded');
  }).catchError((e) => print(e));
}
```

Console error

```
  I/flutter ( 3284): Another exception was thrown: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Comment: "it generates an error." please add the error output

Comment: console error added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes are missing

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> data = <dynamic, dynamic>{
  'Score': 1.0,
  'completion': false,
};
```

Firestore only accepts valid JSON and for that quotes are required.
In JS they can be omitted because all object keys are strings, but in Dart they can be other types as well (but not for JSON).